# Getting paperjs to work in an electron app

Tags: electron, paperjs

Another learning project in the works... I am trying to use paperjs in an electron app.
According to the [instructions](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/#installing-paperjs-using-npm), I *think* I should be using `paper-jsdom` (please correct me if I'm wrong). BTW, I am using TypeScript if that makes a difference. I have an HTML document with nothing but an empty `<canvas>` and a `<script>` tag referencing this:

```
import paper, {Color, Point, Path} from 'paper-jsdom'

window.onload = (): void => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("workspace") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    paper.setup(canvas);

    let path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = Color.random();
    let start = new Point(100, 100);
    path.moveTo(start);
    path.lineTo(start.add(new Point(200, -50)));
    paper.view.update();
};
```

So right off the bat I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: paper_jsdom_1.Path is not a constructor

Ugh... So I tried a few random things (it's late, I'm tired...) and changing my `import` to:

```
import paper from 'paper'
import {Color, Point, Path} from 'paper-jsdom'
```

works, or at least the code above works.

Am I supposed to be importing some things from 'paper' and others from 'paper-jsdom'? What is the correct way to use paperjs in an electron app?

Unfortunately `paper-jsdom` doesn't seem to have any type info for TS.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `Paper.js` in the renderer process of `Electron`, you are using it in the browser context and not in `Node.js` context so you should use the common `paper` package which relies on browser `Canvas API` (and not `paper-jsdom` which targets browserless usage).
So you should be able to use `Paper.js` as you would for a website.

From your code example, I see that you are using `TypeScript` so you can have a look at this simple quickstart project that I made to play with `Paper.js` and `TypeScript`.
It uses this kind of import:

```js
import * as paper from 'paper';
```

And then access `Paper.js` classes through the imported `paper` object:

```js
new paper.Path.Circle({
    center   : paper.view.center,
    radius   : 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
});
```

### Edit

Here is a [repository](https://github.com/sasensi/paperjs-electron) showing the simplest way of using `Paper.js` in an `Electron` app.